# How to delete Gwibber history?

Tags: delete, gwibber, history

How do I delete Gwibber history in 11.10? I deleted the account and created the account again, but some of the tweets deleted on the web still appear on Gwibber.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gwibber holds its data in a SQL database which you can view and amend if you use `sqlitebrowser`

```
sudo apt-get install sqlitebrowser

cd ~/.config/gwibber
sqlitebrowser gwibber.sqlite
```

[image: sqlitebrowser screenshot]

Change the database table to *messages* - highlight the messages you want to delete - click the delete button and then save the database changes.

Note - Gwibber appears to hold your account and messages in memory - so you may have to reboot if a gwibber-refresh action doesn't work.

Note 2- if you just want to start from a clean database - just delete gwibber.sqlite and reboot.  When you next start Gwibber, the database will be recreated and you will need to re-add you twitter/facebook accounts again.

Comment: thnx - works like a charm.